# Get response from PHP code by Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html

I try to send the data from the HTML form to php code by Ajax and it does not get the response

the html form get user_id from the user entry then send it by java script function that handle ajax code and send the user_id to php code to get user_id by `$user_id = $_GET['user_id'];` and search by the user_id then show what ever in php code in the other html code to show div content show`document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` response from php

```js
function showUser(str) {
  if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/gpms/admin_modify_user.php?user_id=" + str, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://localhost/gpms/admin_user.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form method=post>
    <label> Enter User ID: </label>
    <input id="user_id" type=text name=user_id>
    <br><br>
    <input id="modify" type=submit value=Modify onclick="<script>showUser(user_id);</script>">
  </form>

</body>
```

```css
<?php

    $user_id = $_GET['user_id'];
    
    //create connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","gpms");

    // Check connection
    if (!$conn) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($row == 0) {
            echo "No Results";
        }
        else {
            $id = $row['user_id'];
            $name = $row['user_name'];
            $password = $row['user_password'];
     $email = $row['user_email'];
            $department = $row['user_department'];
            
            echo "<div id = demo>";
                echo "<table>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td> ID </td><td> Name </td><td> Password </td><td> E-mail </td><td> Department </td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                    echo "<tr>";
                        echo '<td> '. $id .' </td><td> '. $name .' </td><td> '. $password .' </td><td> '. $email .' </td><td> '. $department .' </td>';
                    echo "</tr>";    
                echo "</table>";
            
                echo "<button onclick = 'editUser(\"$id\",\"$name\",\"$password\",\"$email\",\"$department\")' > Edit </button>";
                echo "<button onclick = 'deleteUser(".$id.")' > Delete </button>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    } 
    else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
 
    $conn->close();
    ?>
```

Comment: Say no to `ActiveXObject` and `Mysqli`, use `XMLHttpRequest` and `PDO`

Comment: You shouldn't have `<script>` in the `onclick` attribute.

Comment: You should use `if($result){` instead of `if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){`

Comment: It is a good practice to quote all of your attribute values.  Do you want to both run the ajax and submit the form?  I'm guessing no.

Comment: Your `editUser()` values have escaped quoting which is going to cause trouble.  I feel like you haven't done your fair share of research on this task because it is riddled with errors.  Please try harder to self-solve before posting questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Your `onclick` attribute is wrong. It should just be the Javascript code, it shouldn't have `<script>...</script>` around it.

```
<input id="modify" type=submit value=Modify onclick="showUser(user_id);">
```

If you had looked in your Javascript console you would have seen it complain of a syntax error when you clicked.

And in the PHP, this line:

```
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
```

should be:

```
if ($result) {
```

Otherwise you do the same query twice, which is unnecessary.